# как создать запрос where с двумя условиями?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, условия

есть 3 столба: 1-id 2-валюта, 3-значение.
как сделать запрос, чтобы из таблицы вытащить сразу данные

1. id='USD' и значение<=1000
2. id='Rub' и значение<=6500

Сделал так, не работает:

```
WHERE amount<=1000 and currency='USD', amount<=65000 and currency='Rub'
```

Comment: `WHERE (amount<=1000 and currency='USD') or (amount<=65000 and currency='Rub')`

Comment: Написал как ответ

Comment: @Амирхон Добавьте в вопрос явно указание, что Вам нужны ID, где ХОТЯ БЫ ОДНО условие истинно. Потому как если, например, нужны ID, для которых оба условия истинны, или для которых ни одно условие не ложно, то запросы будут совершенно иными.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для формирования сложного запроса в MySQL можно использовать все логические операторы а так же `()` скобки.

Ваш запрос будет выглядеть так:

```
SELECT * FROM t WHERE (amount<=1000 and currency='USD') or (amount<=65000 and currency='Rub')
```

Так же в вашем случае можно(но не нужно) было воспользоваться `Union`

```
(SELECT * FROM t WHERE amount<=1000 and currency='USD')
UNION ALL -- спасибо @Akina за коментарий
(SELECT a FROM t WHERE amount<=65000 and currency='Rub');
```

Comment: Поскольку записи из первого подзапроса в принципе не могут быть дубликатами с записями второго подзапроса, лучше `UNION ALL` - какой смысл сортировать объединённый набор, если там всё одно нечего отсеивать?

Comment: @Akina Неусмотрел, спасибо за коментарий.